# Php: echo mot executing properly in wamp from server

Tags: php, azure, cakephp-2.3

I am using windows server 2008 r2 (azure) I installed wamp3.0 to run my pjp web application

The funny thing is my code works perfectly from localhost (when I connecr from the server's browser) but when I try it from client machine echo is not working

Eg: 
 echo ("test"); // not working from client

Everything else is working properly (var_dump ... )

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the log at `c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log`.

You can enable the error reporting by uncommenting (remove the semicolon) the following line in `php.ini` file.

```
;error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```